Как разместить дату сверху, а название месяца снизу и задать каждому свой класс?
Всем привет.
Прошу дельного совета, как зарместить название месяца под датой что бы задать каждому элементу свой стиль? 
Теперь подробнее:
В wordpress использую плагин ACF что бы задать поля.
Создал название поля: "data_cont_front"
Вывожу следующим кодом:
<div class="new-front-cart__span"><?php the_field('data_cont_front'); ?></div>

В итоге получаю дату строкой:


<div class="new-front-cart__span">30 сентября</div>



Вопрос:
Как задать класс для числового значения даты и отдельный класс для названия месяца?

На стороне сервера получай день и месяц... Записывай их в разные теги с нужными классами.

Спасибо за совет, но мне нужно получить не текущую дату, а дату с кастомного поля ACF.
Сама дата приходит, но как её разбить, и добавить классы ума не приложу :)

Ну по пробелу разбей.

Всем спасибо!
Задачу я решил!
На всякий случай, если кому-то будет полезно, вот моё решение:


$date_front= get_field('data_cont_front');
// Разделяем строку на части
$date_parts = explode(' ', $date_front);

// Проверяем, что у нас есть две части: месяц и число
if (count($date_parts) === 2) {
    $number = $date_parts[0]; // Число
        $month = $date_parts[1]; // Название месяца
    
    // Формируем итоговый HTML с классами
    $formatted_date = '<span class="new-date__number">' . htmlspecialchars($number) . '</span> ' .
                      '<span class="new-date__month">' . htmlspecialchars($month) . '</span>';
    
} else {
    echo "Неверный формат даты.";
}

echo $formatted_date; // Вывод результата



